# Reuse association in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

Let's say I have an app that has apartment units.  It also has amenities, and garage_types.  There are also locations.  And each location may have differrent units, amenities, and garage_types. So I create the following factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :unit do
    name '608'
    site
    garage_type
    amenity
  end

  factory :garage_type do
    name 'garage_type a'
    site
  end

  factory :amenity do
    name 'amenity one'
    site
  end

  factory :site do
    name            'Site One'
    phone           '5121234567'
  end
end
```

As you can see each factory references a site.  But when the unit is created, it creates it's associated site and also creates the garage_type and amenity which each also create a site. So how do I get the unit and its associated factories to all use the same site instead of each creating a new site?

Answer (score 3):

You can use factorygirl [callbacks](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)

I don't know your associations, so here's an example:

```
factory :unit do
    name '608'
    after(:build) {|unit| unit.sites = [FactoryGirl.create(:site)]}
end 

factory :site do
   name            'Site One'
   phone           '5121234567'
   after(:build) {|site| site.garage_types = [FactoryGirl.create(:garage_type)]}
end
```

If you create a `unit` using factory, then after building that `unit` it will create a new associated `site` for the newly created `unit`. Then after creating a `site` it will create an associated `garage_type`.

Comment: they all belong_to :site

Comment: @kidbrax I assumed it is as `unit has_many sites`. You just check the example and url for writing  your own.

Comment: But the factory for unit would trigger the creation of a garage_type which would need the same site that was created in your example.

Comment: @kidbrax, Code edited. Now, I guess you can see how to do that for further associated models.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I'll give that a shot tomorrow. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
   site = FactoryGirl.create(:site)
   unit = FactoryGirl.create(:unit, site: site)
   garage_type = FactoryGirl.create(:garage_type, site: site)
   amenity = FactoryGirl.create(:amenity, site: site)
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i had but it kept trying to create a new site and thus giving me unique validation errors. (site name must be unique).  But that would also mean that i would have to do that every time instead of letting the factory handle it.